# Plot hist2d with weights

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, weighted-graph

I need to plot a `hist2d` with contour curves and colorbar from a pandas dataframe.

The dataframe has three cols:

```
x_col, y_col, z_col
```

I want to plot something like this where `z_col` are the weights of the `hist2d`:

[image]

But I don't know how to transform the z_col into a weight 1D array from the hist2d function.

```
fdf = df.groupby([valueX, valueY], as_index=False).mean().sort([valueX, valueY])
x = fdf[valueX]
y = fdf[valueY]
z = fdf[valueZ]

(... axes instantiation)

bins = 100

counts, xbins, ybins, image = axes.hist2d(x, y, bins=bins, normed=True, weights=z)
axes.contour(counts, extent=[xbins.min(), xbins.max(), ybins.min(), ybins.max()], linewidths=3)

pc = axes.pcolor(counts, cmap=cm.jet)
fig.colorbar(pc)

axes_x.hist(x, bins=bins)
axes_y.hist(y, bins=bins, orientation='horizontal')
```

Comment: Could you provide a minimal working example? Also it is unclear what fails in your code: What error do you get?

Comment: My problem is that I don't know what matplotlib expect in the weight parameter and I don't know how to make the 1D array from a pandas dataframe column.

Comment: Please show us the whole traceback in your question

Comment: Sorry, I did not express myself well. That code does not give me any error. But I am not sure about how matplotlib uses the weight params. The documentacion says: "An array of values w_i weighing each sample (x_i, y_i)". But my z var is an Pandas Series. Is it ok?

Comment: You are asking different questions. I would break your question into two or three different questions.

Comment: try http://corner.readthedocs.io

Answer (score -1):

You have to enter an array with the same length of x or y (these ones must have the same length, too)

Since z_col is a column in the dataframe, it will have the right dimension (the same as x_col or y_col)

To get an array you need: dataframe.z_col.values this is an array). On the other side, dataframe.z_col is a pandas series