# How 2D histogram in Matplotlib (hist2D) works?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In documentation of the [hist2d function](https://matplotlib.org/2.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d.html) :

```
plt.hist2d(x,y , weights=weight)
```

x and y and weights are array_like, with shape of (n, ).

According to the documentation, one of outputs is:

> h : 2D array
>
> The bi-dimensional histogram of samples x and y. Values
>   in x are histogrammed along the first dimension and values in y are
>   histogrammed along the second dimension.

How this 2D array is created? imagine

```
x = np.arange(1,10)
y = np.arange(1,10)
weights = x * y
```

How the 2D array created out of these?

I am reparaphrasing the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28150228/plot-hist2d-with-weights-in-pandas-matplotlib) before (it is not mine).

Comment: Are you asking how matplotlib itself creates this 2D array?

Comment: @DavidG  -  Yes, I'm not sure if it makes sense. Maybe I've  misunderstood the role of `weights`.

Comment: You can follow the source code if you wish :-) matplotlib hist2d calls [`numpy.histogram2d`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.16.1/numpy/lib/twodim_base.py#L571-L701) which itself calls [`numpy.histogramdd`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.16.1/numpy/lib/histograms.py#L924-L1102)

Comment: @DavidG, Thanks. I have to! ;-) . Best and the only way to figure out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2D histogramming works the same as 1D histogramming. You define some bins, find out inside of which bin each of your data points are, then count the number of points in each bin. If the histogram is weighted, add up the weights instead of just counting the number.

As example take

```
x = [1.6, 2.3, 2.7]
y = [0.7, 1.8, 1.3]
```

and we want to bin those into the bins with the edges

```
bins = [0,1,2,3]
```

additionally, you may have weights like

```
weights = [0.6, 1, 2]
```

To visualize the situation,

```
sc = plt.scatter(x,y,c=weights, vmin=0)
plt.colorbar(sc)

plt.xticks(bins)
plt.yticks(bins)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now we can histogram by bare eye:

In the bin *x=1..2, y=0..1*  you have one point. This point has a weight of `0.6` the value for this bin will hence be `0.6`.
In the bin *x=2..3, y=1..2* you have two points. They have weights `1` and `2`. Hence the value for that bin is `1+2=3`.

All the other bins are empty. In total your histogram hence looks like

```
[[ 0.0, 0.6, 0.0 ]
 [ 0.0, 0.0, 3.0 ]
 [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ]]
```

and this is indeed what we get when letting numpy do the histogramming.

```
values, _, _ = np.histogram2d(x,y, bins=bins, weights=weights)
print(values.T)
```

Note the `.T` transpose though; this is what the sentence "Values in x are histogrammed along the first dimension and values in y are histogrammed along the second dimension." wants to tell you.

`plt.hist2d` is a wrapper for `numpy.histogram2d`, which will then plot this array as an image

```
h,_, _, image = plt.hist2d(x,y,bins=bins, weights=weights)
plt.colorbar(image)
plt.show()
```

[image]

where the values are encoded in color.